# how to send a transaction with web3 and metamask

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to learn how web3 works and I'm creating a simple HTML page to send a transaction, but I'm getting the following error:

```
(inpage.js:1)   MetaMask - RPC Error: validateTxParams@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:80654
e/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:65579
_@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230907
[1286]</w/o._invoke@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230697
[1286]</E/</e[t]@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2231083
n@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630306
[254]</r.default/</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630285
S@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:930364
[254]</r.default/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630241
[25]</$</<.value</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:66281
e/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:64573
_@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230907
[1286]</w/o._invoke@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230697
[1286]</E/</e[t]@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2231083
n@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630306
[254]</r.default/</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630285
S@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:930364
[254]</r.default/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630241
[25]</$</<.value</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:65202
e/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:175590
_@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230907
[1286]</w/o._invoke@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2230697
[1286]</E/</e[t]@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:2231083
n@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630306
[254]</r.default/</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630285
S@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:930364
[254]</r.default/<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:630241
[70]</t.exports</<.value</<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:175752
[609]</t.exports/<.eth_sendTransaction<@moz-extension://e67892be-b68e-4c30-a024-c6ded3ddf733/background.js:1:1218722
```

Here's the code:

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: '0xbe03ede9d060679c18df54dbdbde924b0261075b',
        to: "0xA396923aD14c3CcA2Af9D0C5BC97A5180416E700",
        value: "0.01"
    }, function(error, hash){
        alert(error);
    });
```

Comment: Change `"0.01"` to `"10e+16"`.

Comment: thanks. How can I estimate the gas if I'm sending data? I've found it's 21000 + 68*byte, but I'm guessing there's a better way of doing so @goodvibration

Comment: Are you asking this in order to determine the gas-limit? Just put in a little extra, you'll get back te difference between what you've put and what was actually used.

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum transaction don't accept float point as their value,  the value will be send is the value in wei so if you want to send 0.01 ether u have to take 0.01 * 10 ^ 18 to get the wei and then send it. You can also use web3.eth.toWei